# Where do I occur?

Tags: riddle, word

The answer to this riddle is indirect. Based on what the riddle reveals, it asks where that which you find occurs. That will be the correct answer.

```
You try to avoid me.

I might occur in a variety of colors.

You might see my color change over time.

I can be eased.

You can cover me up or hide me.

I can show what's underneath.
```

Where do I occur?

Comment: Wow, 2 answers already and only 3 views!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're talking about

> a bruise

You try to avoid me.

> nobody like to hurt themselves

I might occur in a variety of colors.

> it can be blue, green, yellow

You might see my color change over time.

> in the process of disappearing, it changes color

I can be eased.

> if you take painkiller, it will make it easier to live with

You can cover me up or hide me.

> you can put some make up on it or hide it under clothes

I can show what's underneath.

> it shows the blood underneath the skin

It occurs when

> knock yourself on a hard surface

It occurs

> on your body

Comment: This was indeed what I meant. Very impressive to see multiple logical answers that made sense, even tho I didn't even realize that myself :)

Comment: Excellent! I agree that this fits the riddle better than my answer. +1

Comment: I think the "being able to be eased" and the "hiding" part made it maybe too obvious? Maybe I should be more cryptic? :)

Comment: Actually the "ease" was the last thing I found. The hiding was not that obvious to me.

Answer (score 8):

Probably not the intended answer, but it could be:

> heat

occurring in

> a fire.

*You try to avoid me.*

> You don't want to get burned.

*I might occur in a variety of colors.*

> Red-hot, white-hot, yellow and orange flames, blue gas flames.

*You might see my color change over time.*

> Red-hot coals can turn white-hot over time.

*I can be eased.*

> "Eased" meaning extinguished maybe.

*You can cover me up or hide me.*

> You can smother a fire.

*I can show what's underneath.*

> When something has all burned away to nothing, you can then see what was underneath it.

Comment: Omg I didn't even mean that and it fits the description perfectly. So cool that all the explanations are totally valid even tho I didn't mean that. Loving it! :) +1